# Change editorconfig so Github recognizes Dockerfile.bedrock as a Dockerfile

Tags: git, github, editorconfig

How can I create an .editorconfig file for a Git repo, so that Github.com can recognize certain extensions? Specifically looking to recognize a file called in Dockerfile.x as a Dockerfile.

Comment: Is `.editorconfig` something different than https://editorconfig.org/? That project seems geared towards standardization across text editors and IDE's, not Github.

Comment: @JakeWorth I believe Github also considers it a standard and displays things differently in the browser given that file in a project

Comment: GitHub doesn't consider `.editorconfig` files for language detection. The language detector they use, Linguist, has no code to read them. You need to use `.gitattributes` or a Vim or Emacs modeline.

Comment: if a file has a shebang/hashbang, then that is enough sometimes for github.com. Is there a shebang/hashbang we can use for dockerfiles?

Answer (score 1):

Would something like `.gitattributes` be useful?

Here's an example `.gitattributes`, tailored to your use case:

```
# Reclassifies `.bedrock` files as Dockerfiles:
*.bedrock linguist-language=Dockerfile
```

[Git attributes docs](https://github.com/github/linguist#using-gitattributes)

Comment: yeah I wasn't sure if gitattributes or editorconfig was the right approach

Comment: Yeah sorry this didn't seem to work on Github.com, I might withdraw my upvote, but I won't downvote

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you've tried? Or possibly link to a repo where it isn't working? This example is an adaptation from the docs of the project Github uses to classify files; it should work with perhaps a bit of experimentation.

Comment: yeah I tried it at work in a private repo but will try it in  a public repo and link to it if it don't work

Comment: This seems like a pretty common technique (~400 examples): https://github.com/search?q=linguist-language%3DDockerfile&type=Code . Those that match on `*` are classified on their repo page as 100% Dockerfile.